# Using Url.Action in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to use the Url.Action method to correctly generate the required Url for an ajax call but I'm running into problems when trying to build the RouteValues, here's the problem line of code:

```
var url = @Url.Action("ViewFile", "Default", new { itemId = $(this).data("itemid") });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to assign the result of the JQuery `$(this).data("itemid")`
to `itemId` in the RouteValues.

Is there a way using razor syntax which will allow this code to compile?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are confusing client side with server side. Try something like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ViewFile", "Default")?itemId=' + $(this).data("itemid");
```

when you write a `@` with razor view engine, you are writing a instruction that will be process on the server side at the end of this command. In your case you want to add a parameter in the url that comes from the javascript, so, just concat on the client side the value with the url generated by the `@Url` helper.

*PS: I am assuming you are using the Default Route Tables.*

Comment: Ah, Of course the Jquery wont run when the server side code executes, how silly of me.  Thanks. [Hangs head in shame]

Comment: just a heads up, this will not work on javascripts outside Views

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to create a place holder and then replace it:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetOrderDetails", "Home", new { id = "js-id" })'
              .replace("js-id", encodeURIComponent(rowId));
```