# Send Jquery UI Dialog value to Url.Action

Tags: jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Not sure how to pass along a bool to my (working) C# method DeleteTestuser. I've Googled the heck out of this but mileage varies with all kinds of pitfalls, i.e. old information, bad syntax.

Rather than passing confirm as false, below, I need to return a bool if the user confirms the action. Thanks...

index.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteTestUser", "Home",
    new {id = testUser.TestUserId, confirm = false})" 
id="confirm-delete">
```

_layout.cshtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#dialog-modal').dialog(
            {
                title: 'Test User',
                draggable: false,
                resizeable: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Yes': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        confirmResult(true);

                    },
                    'No': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        confirmResult(false);
                    }
                }
            });

        $('#confirm-delete').click(function () {
            $('#dialog-modal').dialog("open");
        });

        function confirmResult(result) { return result }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Twisty As is, nothing is wrong strictly speaking, but I need to pass along a bool from the dialog to DeleteTestUser, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to alter the `href` value using javascript . But you may as well just use `href="#"` in the link, and then your script uses `location.href = ".."` to do the redirect

Comment: First, your `button` format is not correct. `buttons: [{ text: "Yes", click: function(){} }, { text: "No", click: function(){} }]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're recreating your own `confirm()` with jQuery UI Dialog. I did this and here is a similar case: [confirm form submit with jquery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453976/confirm-form-submit-with-jquery-ui)

Apply this to your scenario and you have something like:

```js
$(function() {
  function ui_confirm(message, callback) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var dialog = $("<div>", {
        id: "confirm"
      })
      .html(message)
      .appendTo($("body"))
      .data("selection", false)
      .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Confirm',
        zIndex: 99999999,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
          text: "Yes",
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dfd.resolve(true);
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
              callback.apply();
            }
          }
        }, {
          text: "No",
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dfd.resolve(false);
          }
        }],
        close: function(event, ui) {
          $('#confirm').remove();
        }
      });
    dialog.dialog("open");
    return dfd.promise();
  }
  
  function deleteUser(id){
    // Code you will execute to delete a user or POST back.
  }
  
  $(".button").button();
  $('.del').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // your code

    $.when(ui_confirm("Are you sure?")).done(function(val) {
      if (val) {
        console.log("Delete User Confirmed.");
        deleteUser($(this).attr("id"));
      } else {
        console.log("Do not delete user.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
John Smith <a href="#del-user" class="del button" id="user-0001">Delete</a>
```

You may be able to get away with just executing specific callbacks. That's up to you. This code can then also be used to pass along another function or to use with a `prompt()` like dialog.

**Update**

See: [Using Url.Action in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701510/using-url-action-in-javascript)

For example:

```
function deleteTestUser(uid, conf){
  var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteTestUser", "Home", new {id=' + uid + ', confirm=' + conf + '})';
  $.get(url, function(data){
    console.log("User " + uid + " Deleted.");
  });
}
```

I would use POST if possible.

```
function deleteTestUser(uid, conf){
  $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteTestUser", "Home")', { id: uid, confirm: conf }, function(data){
    console.log("User " + uid + " Deleted.");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will delve into this more later today but I may have been unclear. My essential need is to pass along the confirmation dialog selection (true or false) ultimately to a C# method via razor. I'm not sure what you've provided does that, precisely. So js --> razor -- C#

Comment: @Steve I did not provide that since you did not indicated how you wanted to do that. I suspect a POST back would be best. This is akin to an AJAX Post to a backend Razor or C# script.

Comment: @Steve updated my answer a bit. Looks like you can use GET. I do not use Razor nor do a lot with C#, so had to look it up.

Comment: Thank you Twisty. I will give that a try. Also I realized I may just be looking at this the wrong way. Rather than trying to pass around a bool, maybe I just need to redirect away if the user cancels the delete operation.

Comment: Your answer may indeed work, but really I was asking the wrong question. I need to either cancel or post to the Url.Action. I don't need to pass a boolean around. Thanks