# how to set confirmation message before remove tag in Tagify Jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need confirmation message "Yes" or "No" before removing a tag.

Plugin link is here: https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/

Anyone can help me?

```
<input name="tag_name" id="tagInput" placeholder="" value="">

<script>
var tagInput = document.querySelector('input[name="tag_name"]');
    tagify = new Tagify(tagInput, {
        whitelist: [],
        maxTags: 1000,
        dropdown: {
            maxItems: 5,           // <- mixumum allowed rendered suggestions
            classname: "tags-look", // <- custom classname for this dropdown, so it could be targeted
            enabled: 0,             // <- show suggestions on focus
            closeOnSelect: true    // <- do not hide the suggestions dropdown once an item has been selected
        }
});

tagify.on('remove', function(e) {
    console.log('removed');
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried [window confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: Yes I know, but I need only confirmation before removing a tag.

Comment: Might be possible that i'm understanding something wrong, you want a user confirmation before doing something?

Comment: Yes, If the user says yes then after removing a tag. but not happened.

Comment: then that is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will want to program the click of one of the buttons, the close, or investigate https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ For more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, you can do something like this:

```
tagify.on('remove', function(e) {
  var a = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove '" + e.detail.data.value + "'?");
  if(a){
    console.log('removed');
  }
  return a;
});
```

If you want a UI Dialog solution, take a look at these:

[confirm form submit with jquery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453976/confirm-form-submit-with-jquery-ui)

[Send Jquery UI Dialog value to Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227256/send-jquery-ui-dialog-value-to-url-action/49229921#49229921)

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback hook for tag removal:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input')
var tagify = new Tagify(input,{
    hooks: {
        /**
         * Removes a tag
         * @param  {Array}  tags [Array of Objects [{node:..., data:...}, {...}, ...]]
         */
        beforeRemoveTag : function( tags ){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                confirm("Remove " + tags[0].data.value + "?")
                    ? resolve()
                    : reject()
            })
        }
    }
})
```

https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#hooks

Answer (score 0):

Read the [hooks section](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#hooks) in the docs:

You can use the `beforeRemoveTag` hook:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input')
var tagify = new Tagify(input, {
    hooks: {
        beforeRemoveTag : tags => {
            // set tag loading state
            tagify.tagLoading(tags[0].node, true)

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`)
                    ? resolve()
                    : reject()
                
                // unset tag loading state
                tagify.tagLoading(tags[0].node, false)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body{ font: 16px arial; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input value="xxx, yyy, zzz" placeholder='Try deleting tags'>
```