# How to pass variable defined in scripts to division tag in ASP.NET MVC5 razor view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I just want to pass value of target from script to division tag in mvc.
Here are the codes I have done.

Scripts:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                var target = $(e.target).attr("link") // activated tab
                alert(target);
            });
    </script>
}
```

DIV:(outer division)

```
<div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> &nbsp; News &amp; Events</h5>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("List","News")" style="color: #00a650;font-weight:600;">View All</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I just want value of target to display inside this division.

Where: 
News in `@URl.Action("List","News")` should be replaced by target's value.

Comment: Yo want to add `<b> target </b>` as the last element of your outer div?

Comment: yes outer division

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Url.Action in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701510/using-url-action-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access javascript variable within @URL.Action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456703/how-to-access-javascript-variable-within-url-action)

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an id then use [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the html:

```
<div id="Target">
..
..
<b> target </b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, answer was satisfactory but there is a little change in question.